# Back up and restore all databases and users with Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-workbench, database-restore

I am trying to migrate all our sites over to a new server, and each database has a different user specific to that database.  Is there a way to back up all the databases and users in one giant file to restore on the other server?

So far I've only seen stuff to do one database at a time.

One additional note to clarify, this is on a Windows machine.  I'm guessing those are both commands I would run in a terminal on Linux.  Is there a Windows equivalent?

Comment: You can use mysqldump to backup all Databases from the Server and import this on the new Server. Dont forgot to use the -R Option. That will also sore the function and SP. After the Import ALL users from the NewServer are removed and changed to the User and passwords from the old Server

Comment: mysqldump -h ipofServer -R --master-data --single-transaction --all-databases -uroot -p xxx >dbs.sql

Comment: @BerndBuffen Can that be used on Windows?

Comment: i am not the windows guy, bit i have looked in google. Its part of the workbench. and i think that may people use Windows.